# Trying to change string[ ] to rest format in c# as per the example provided

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have the following array list that I am trying to convert so it will update a vendors process for us.

```
"AlertTriggerTime":"Tuesday, April 14, 2020","LastEdit":"Thursday, April 09, 2020", "ObjectType":"Node","Severity:"Critical"
```

And here is what I need it to look like

```
{
    "message": "An example",
    "alias": "Life is too short for no alias",
    "description":"Every alert needs a description",
    "responders":[
        {"AlertTriggerTime":"Tuesday, April 14, 2020"},
        {"LastEdit":"Thursday, April 09, 2020"},
        {"ObjectType":"Node"},
        {"Severity":"Critical"}

    ]
}
```

Comment: What is an "array list"? Can you provide C# code?

Comment: if that is meant to be JSON, that is highly unusual as a layout... are you sure that's what you want? (it isn't even valid JSON, quite)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of doing this, and *exactly how* depends on which parts need to be dynamic. If we assume that none of those keys needs to change (i.e. the structure is pretty fixed), then you could do:

```cs
var obj = new {
    message = "An example",
    alias = "Life is too short for no alias",
    description = "Every alert needs a description",
    responders = new object[] {
        new { AlertTriggerTime = "Tuesday, April 14, 2020" },
        new { LastEdit = "Thursday, April 09, 2020" },
        new { ObjectType = "Node" },
        new { Severity = "Critical" }
    }
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

At the other extreme, everything could be `Dictionary<string, object>` - or somewhere in the middle!

Comment: Thank you, but all the data is dynamic

Comment: @Rick: then `Dictionary<string, object>`